# How to make hover effect stays even after unhover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a simple JSFiddle for the problem. Here is the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/tnkh/Loewjnr3/

CSS:

```
.container{
 background: white;
 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height:50px
}

.circle {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: #0f3757;
 -moz-border-radius: 50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 margin-left:10px;
 float:left;
 transition: all 0.3s ease
}

.circle:hover {
 background:orange;
}
```

Basically over here, I can hover on any circle to change their color. I would like to ask how could I make the orange color stays on on any particular circle that I hovered on after the mouse moved away to white container?

Any script or CSS animation I could use to solve the problem?

Comment: So, when you move out of white container, it should be removed?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Nope, the hover effect should stay on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an `mouseover` event to `.circle` element and write an `active` CSS class which has `background-color` property and when `event` occurs remove `active` class from any `.circle` and add it to current `element`

**JS**

```
$(".container span.circle").on('mouseover',function(){
    $(".circle").removeClass('active');//remove from other elements
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
  background:orange;
  transition: all 0.5s ease
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Loewjnr3/1/)**

Comment: Good answer bud +1

Comment: Wow someone is jealous of the solution provided. -LOL-

Comment: @CodeMonkey.. That's why SO makes me sad sometimes.. :(

Answer (score 2):

Using JQuery you can add a class to an element as such:

```
$(element).on('hover', function() {
    // this if you're hovering over the element that would change, otherwise rename 'this' to whatever element class or id you want to change 
    $(this).addClass('NameOfClass');
});
```

You can then have that class in CSS

```
.NameOfClass {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

And then just remove that class when you want.

Answer (score 2):

> Change `.circle:hover` to `.hover`

```
.hover {
  background:orange;
  transition: all 0.5s ease
}
```

**A) IF you want orange color be forever :**

> Use this `jquery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.circle').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.circle').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    })
})
```

```css
.container{
    background: white;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:50px
}

.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #0f3757;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    transition: all 0.5s ease
}

.hover {
    background:orange;
    transition: all 0.5s ease
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "container">
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
</div>
```

**B) If you want orange color be until mouse move on other circle**

> Use this `jquery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.circle').hover(function(){
        $('.circle').removeClass('hover');
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.circle').hover(function(){
        $('.circle').removeClass('hover');
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    })
})
```

```css
.container{
    background: white;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:50px
}

.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #0f3757;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    transition: all 0.5s ease
}

.hover {
    background:orange;
    transition: all 0.5s ease
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "container">
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery to set a class when the mouse is hovered.  Then the class will remain set even after the mouse moves away.

```
$(".circle").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hovered");
});
```

[I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate.](https://jsfiddle.net/WayneA/wm970wt8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".circle" ).mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('background','orange')
  }
)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rtxq9fnu/